# jQuery Animation with Fixed Text

Tags: jquery, animation

[image]

I need to create an above kind of animation where left hand site text should move continuously bottom to top while right hand side text("My Fixed Text") should align with it and that text is fixed (Not moving).How can I achieve it by using jQuery ?

I saw this link but not exactly the my requirement. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCBXz/12/)

```
var ticker = $('#ticker');
var container = $('#ticker > div');
var spacing = ticker.outerHeight() - ticker.height();

function animator(currentItem) {
    var distance = currentItem.outerHeight() + spacing;

    var currentTop = parseInt(container.css('margin-top'), 10);

    var duration = (distance + currentTop) / 0.05;

    container.animate({ marginTop: -distance}, duration, "linear", function() {
        var parent = currentItem.parent();

        currentItem.detach();
        parent.css("marginTop", 5);

        parent.append(currentItem);
        animator(parent.children(":first"));
    });
};
```

Comment: Sorry man i write something wrong, please try to place fixed text in Parallel Div,, I am so sorry man

Comment: @JotDhaliwal Can you please do a small sample on JSFiddle ?

Comment: sure , i am preparing that for you

Comment: Tom has done same i am saying you, please follow that

Comment: You are alwz hearty welcome man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a left- and right-column. The right column floats next to the left one.

See my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/e8svLggw/4

```
var initCarroussel = function(selector, period)
{
    var containerEl  = $(selector);
    var animating    = false;
    setInterval(function(){

        if(animating){
            return;
        } else {
            animating = true;
        }

        // Clone the first item
        var carrousselEl    = containerEl.find('.carroussel');
        var firstEl         = carrousselEl.children().first();
        var clonedEl        = firstEl.clone();

        carrousselEl.append(clonedEl);

        carrousselEl.animate({
            marginTop: [0 -30] 
        },period-100,'swing',function(){
            firstEl.remove();
            carrousselEl.css('margin-top', 0);
            animating = false;
        });

    },period);
}

$(function(){
    initCarroussel('#myCarroussel', 1000); 
});
```

Comment: Wow.. Unbelievable Tom.Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Great Buddy ... Cheers @TomLankhorst

Comment: There is small issue on it.That is when I go to another page and come back it shows items are duplicated.Please can you correct that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sampath, would sure like but I can't reproduce your problem. Can you send me a link or something?

Comment: Yes.You just need to open the fiddler which you have done here and let it run.After that go to the another web page and come back the previously open JSfiddle page.Then it should show as duplicate items.Please check that.

Comment: Implemented a 'debouncer'. When the browser doesn't have the page in focus it gets a bit loosely on timing, that caused the first element not to be removed.

Comment: Have you updated the above JSFiddler with the changes ?

Comment: You are GREAT Tom.Thanks a lot.Have a Nice Day Ahead ! :)

Comment: @TomLankhorst If you can please give me a support for this post.Thanks in advance.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742816/jquery-image-animation-with-fixed-text

Comment: Hi Sampath. I do think that based on my previous answer you could at least give it a try. It's just a variation on my previous answer. Instead of copying the first list item to the bottom each time, you now have to copy the whole image after every 5 slides. Please give it a try and if you can't get it to work I'll have a look at it.